# How to compare strstr(LPCWSTR, CHAR*);

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++

```
LPCWSTR location_url;
m_spWebBrowser->get_LocationURL((BSTR*)&location_url);
```

How do I compare `LPCWSTR`  with `const char *` in `strstr` ?

Example:

```
if(strstr((location_url, ".html"))
```

Comment: `get_LocationURL()` returns an actual `BSTR`, not an `LPWSTR`. You need to fix your variable declaration. And do not forget to call `SysFreeString()` when you are done using it, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make your target extension a wide string also and use [wcsstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
wchar_t* ext = L".html";
if (wcsstr(location_url, ext))
```